What does it mean have multiple cluster points?
In my classes we have just talked about one cluster point but in an excercise says "has one and only one cluster point", does that mean a sequence can have more than one?

Please add more details to your question. For example, are you talking about real sequences? And what is your definition of cluster point. That being said, consider the sequence defined by $a_n=(-1)^n$. What are its cluster points?

Please don't make your question picture-only; pictures are neither accessible nor searchable. Be so kind as to type out the text; it's not that long.

The existence of a cluster point is given by the definition above, but it does not mean that it is the only cluster point of a set. A convergent sequence must have only one limit (otherwise it wouldn´t converge).
